# Auth0 /authorize endpoint not returning a JWT

Tags: oauth, auth0

I am trying to use the following enpoint for social authentication with auth0.

`https://YOUR_NAMESPACE/authorize`

The documentation clearly states that given the `response_type=token` we should recieve an `access_token` and an `id_token` in the hash fragment.

[image: Directly under "remarks"]
https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#!#get--authorize_social

But for whatever reason, I only get back the `access_token`. The login seems to work fine, and authenticate with google, but when redirected to the callback, the `id_token` is just missing. The `access_token`, `state`, and `token_type` are present at-least.

I've attempted using the `/oauth/access_token` endpoint to receive the `id_token` given I already have the `access_token`, but making that request (I've triple checked I'm doing it correctly) always yields a `401 unauthorized`.

Auth0 is clearly a worthwhile product, so I very much doubt its straight up not working. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Googling around has not been helpful so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure where the docs say that `response_type=token` would deliver both an `access_token` and an `id_token` in the fragment but the OAuth 2.0/OpenID Connect specifications themselves say that `token` should return just an `access_token` and instead the `token id_token` response type would deliver both. I guess that's worth a try. Also make sure that you include the scope `openid` in the authorization request.